# Python: Dictionary to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I would like to change the dictionary to pandas dataframe.

```
data = {u'Diluted Normalized EPS': [{u'date': u'2020-01-03', u'value': u'-0.446810'}, {u'date': u'2019-10-04', u'value': u'-0.765540'}, {u'date': u'2019-06-28', u'value': u
'-0.574240'}, {u'date': u'2019-03-29', u'value': u'-2.063700'}, {u'date': u'2018-12-28', u'value': u'-0.841380'}], u'Net Income Before Extra. Items': [{u'date': u'2020-01-03', u'value': u'-139.000000'}, {u'date': u'2019-10-04', u'value': u'-276.000000'}, {u'date': u'2019-06-28', u'value': u'-185.000000'}, {u'date': u'2019-03-29', u'value': u'-652.000000'}, {u'date': u'2018-12-28', u'value': u'-257.000000'}]}
```

I would like to convert to Pandas dataframe as below

```
         date  Diluted Normalized EPS  Net Income Before Extra. Items
0  2020-01-03  -0.446810                -139.000000
1  2019-10-04  -0.765540                -276.000000
2  2019-06-28  -0.574240                -185.000000
3  2019-03-29  -2.063700                -652.000000
4  2018-12-28  -0.841380                -257.000000
```

`pd.DataFrame(data)` unable to return the desired results

Comment: It looks like you have to modify your dictionary, or maybe think about sequentially building your dataframe. Good Luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use nested dictionary comprehension with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
d = {k:{x['date']: x['value'] for x in v} for k, v in data.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame(d).rename_axis('date').reset_index()
print(df)
         date Diluted Normalized EPS Net Income Before Extra. Items
0  2020-01-03              -0.446810                    -139.000000
1  2019-10-04              -0.765540                    -276.000000
2  2019-06-28              -0.574240                    -185.000000
3  2019-03-29              -2.063700                    -652.000000
4  2018-12-28              -0.841380                    -257.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the below code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data).apply(
    lambda col: pd.DataFrame(col.tolist()).set_index('date').value)\
    .reset_index()
```

Steps:

1. `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)` - creates a temporary DataFrame.
   It has 2 columns (keys of your dictionary). Each cell contains a dictionary,
   containing 2 keys (*date* and *value*).
2. `pd.DataFrame(col.tolist())` - the first part of the *lambda* function -
   converts the current column into another temporary DataFrame,
   with 2 columns (*date* and *value*).
3. `set_index('date')` - changes *date* column into the index.
4. `value` - takes only *value* column from the above DataFrame.
5. `apply(...)` - application of the above *lambda* function converts the
   first temporary DataFrame into almost exactly what we want, i.e. 2 required
   columns with *date* as the index.
6. `reset_index()` - converts the index into a regular column.